# djangosaml2idp problems with launch: saml2.sigver.MissingKey: http://localhost:8000/saml2/metadata/

Tags: python, django, saml-2.0, django-saml2-auth

I'v been trying to launch project(example_setup folder):

https://github.com/OTA-Insight/djangosaml2idp/tree/master/example_setup

I can anybody answer to men according with documentation. But it does not working. First problem, as I undesrtand is in date of methadata in `SP(idp_metadata.xml)- validUntil="2020-12-27T12:41:18Z">` . It does not valid at the moment, and was changed to future date, as example`(validUntil="2030-12-27T12:41:18Z")`. But next I got another problem when trying to sign in to `SP(localhost:8000)` in my browser, I have more problem:

```
Error during SAML2 authentication
IncorrectlySigned
```

In attempts to find problem, I found the place where it is occured. In original it iis in tryexcept block, and can't be found easy.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dmitriy/projects/djangosaml2idp/example_setup/idp/djangosaml2idp/views.py", line 251, in get
    req_info = idp_server.parse_authn_request(request.session['SAMLRequest'], binding)
  File "/home/dmitriy/projects/djangosaml2idp/example_setup/idp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/saml2/server.py", line 238, in parse_authn_request
    return self._parse_request(enc_request, AuthnRequest,
  File "/home/dmitriy/projects/djangosaml2idp/example_setup/idp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/saml2/entity.py", line 1036, in _parse_request
    _request = _request.loads(xmlstr, binding, origdoc=enc_request,
  File "/home/dmitriy/projects/djangosaml2idp/example_setup/idp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/saml2/request.py", line 110, in loads
    return self._loads(xmldata, binding, origdoc, must,
  File "/home/dmitriy/projects/djangosaml2idp/example_setup/idp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/saml2/request.py", line 51, in _loads
    print(self.signature_check(xmldata, origdoc=origdoc,
  File "/home/dmitriy/projects/djangosaml2idp/example_setup/idp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/saml2/sigver.py", line 1662, in correctly_signed_authn_request
    return self.correctly_signed_message(decoded_xml, 'authn_request', must, origdoc, only_valid_cert=only_valid_cert)
  File "/home/dmitriy/projects/djangosaml2idp/example_setup/idp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/saml2/sigver.py", line 1653, in correctly_signed_message
    return self._check_signature(
  File "/home/dmitriy/projects/djangosaml2idp/example_setup/idp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/saml2/sigver.py", line 1503, in _check_signature
    raise MissingKey(_issuer)
saml2.sigver.MissingKey: http://localhost:8000/saml2/metadata/
Internal Server Error: /idp/login/process/
```

Some key is missing:

```
Error during SAML2 authentication
MissingKey
http://localhost:8000/saml2/metadata/
```

My idp_metada in the SP is like in the [example_setup][1] folder of project, only validUntil has been changed as I said above, user in IDP has been created as superuser, I also tried to create user in the SP, the same as in the IDP, but nothing changed

Can anybody anser to me, what my problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It's no any information in docs. But you need to create SP inside IDP from admin panel. That was resolved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).